# split string and make columns

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings like this:

```
List["String"] =["I am xyz", "My name is xyz", "myself xyz", "people call me xyz"]
```

I want to split string make two columns like  this :

```
List["list"] = ["I am", "My name is", "myself", "people call me"]
List["Name"] = ["xyz","xyz","xyz","xyz"]
```

Comment: Is always have value 'xyz'?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are actually trying to do, and preferably make an attempt of your own?

Comment: yes. It would be always xyz. I have tried splitting with space and split with (" xy") but it is becoming complected so I needed help.

Comment: @NiraliKhoda please edit your post to clarify your question with all relevant informations, cf my comments on han solo's answer. Also: you obviously want a regexp here.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were going for ? But obviously, this maynot be the answer, because you didn't give us the extreme cases in your input :)

```
>>> x = ["I am xyz", "My name is xyz", "myself xyz", "people call me xyz"]
>>> d = {}
>>> d['list'] = [' '.join(y.split()[:-1]) for y in x]
>>> d['name'] = [y.split()[-1] for y in x]
>>> d
{'list': ['I am', 'My name is', 'myself', 'people call me'], 'name': ['xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz']}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but if i ask there might be some case of "People call me xyz generally".can I still split only "XYZ" to other column @han solo

Comment: @NiraliKhoda it would have been better to __clearly__ explain what you want __before__ someone try to answer - this would prevent everyone from wasting time.

Comment: @NiraliKhoda also, what would you do with the "generally" part then ?

Comment: I wanted to put that code in the comment to get more clarification. But that would not be very readable. And the user didn't gave me a clear explanation to how to extract the name which it said "xyz", and it came in last.

Comment: @NiraliKhoda, please give us a real example and tell us what to filter. With border cases, if possible